# What font is used for Openbox menus?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

Any tip is welcome, as any suggestion of monospaced and pixelized fonts

Answer (score 3):

The asker found it but deleted their account.

> Anyway, I have just found it, thanks guys. It's [Ohsnap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osnapfont/)